# Unix signal function with fork() and exec()

Tags: c, signals, exec, fork

I have a little problem with signal function.

My program in a brief:

```
void sigfunc(int sn)
{
    if(sn == SIGINT)
        printf("SIG TEXT!");
}

int main(void)
{ 
...
 // spawn 10 children and execl my another programs
 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid != 0) {
            signal(SIGINT, sigfunc);
            continue;
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            execl(pathtoprog[i], progname[i], NULL);
    }
// wait for sig (only parent waits because programs from execl have their own while(1))
if(pid > 0)
    while(1) {}
}
```

Problem is simple: when I press Ctrl+C I'll see `SIG TEXT!` but programs started by execl will crash/hang(I'm not sure, because they stop working but still exists in process monitor). How to write this sigfunc to react only for parent process and leave all children with execl alone?

Comment: Sounds like you have some zombie children that you forgot to reap. Don't forget that if you kill a `fork()`'d process (or even if it crashes on its own), you have to call `waitpid()` on it with the parent to harvest the zombie child.

Comment: You only need to call signal(SIGINT, sigfunc); once in the parent